# Embed DWG file in HTML

Tags: html, embed, autocad, dwg, autocad-plugin

I want to ask how to embed DWG file in HTML Page.

I have tried using  tag with Volo Viewer but this solution run only in IE not in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: [Here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2015/05/viewing-50-design-software-formats-from-a-web-page.html) is how.

Answer (score 2):

Dwgview-x can do that, but it will need to be installed as a plug-in on client computers so that anyone  can view the dwg file that you embed online.

Answer (score 1):

There may be third party ActiveX controls that you could use, but I think ultimately you will find that it's not practical for drawing files of even average complexity. I recommend to create DWF (if you need vector format) or PNG files on demand (using e.g. the free DWG TrueView from http://usa.autodesk.com/design-review/ ) and embed those instead.

Answer (score 0):

I use DWG Browser. Its a stand alone program that is used for reporting and categorizing drawings with previews. It saves exports in html too.

They have a free demo download available.

http://www.graytechnical.com/software/dwg-browser/

Answer (score 0):

You'll find what I think is the latest information on Autodesk's labs site here: http://labs.blogs.com/its_alive_in_the_lab/2014/01/share-your-autodesk-360-designs-on-company-web-sites.html

It looks like a DWG can be embeded there is an example on this page, but clearly DWF is the way to go.

Comment: Next time, try to add more from yourself than just a link and one sentence. Link is good only if it connected with your explanation. As I said try to add more next time

Comment: Sorry, I though my comment was clear enough. On the link I provide, there is an example of an embeded DWG just below the sentence "I was able share a doc in 360.autodesk.com as Public, and then it had an EMBED option. I embedded it on a local HTML page, and worked."

So the procedure is straitghforward, share publicly your DWG on https://360.autodesk.com, then you'll see a link called "insert this document in your web site". Copy and paste this code in your web site and... voilà!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed DWG file's content in an HTML page by rendering the file's pages as HTML pages or images. If you find it an attractive solution then you can do it using [GroupDocs.Viewer](https://products.groupdocs.com/viewer/) API that allows you to render the document pages as HTML pages, images, or a PDF document as a whole. You can then include the rendered HTML/image pages or whole PDF document in your HTML page.

**Using C#**

```
ViewerConfig config = new ViewerConfig();
config.StoragePath = "D:\\storage\\";

// Create HTML handler (or ViewerImageHandler for rendering document as image)
ViewerHtmlHandler htmlHandler = new ViewerHtmlHandler(config);

// Guid implies that unique document name 
string guid = "sample.dwg";

// Get document pages in html form
List<PageHtml> pages = htmlHandler.GetPages(guid);

// Or Get document pages in image form using image handler
//List<PageImage> pages = imageHandler.GetPages(guid);

foreach (PageHtml page in pages)
{
    // Get HTML content of each page using page.HtmlContent
}
```

**Using Java**

```
// Setup GroupDocs.Viewer config
ViewerConfig config = new ViewerConfig();
// Set storage path
config.setStoragePath("D:\\storage\\");

// Create HTML handler (or ViewerImageHandler for rendering document as image)
ViewerHtmlHandler htmlHandler = new ViewerHtmlHandler(config);

String guid = "Sample.dwg"

// Get document pages in HTML form
List<PageHtml> pages = htmlHandler.getPages(guid);

for (PageHtml page : pages) {
     // Get HTML content of each page using page.getHtmlContent
}
```

*Disclosure: I work as a Developer Evangelist at GroupDocs.*